# getting specific type of file and adding them to an existing zip file

Tags: php, image, zip, directory, gd

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = "image/files.zip";

    if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }

    $zip->addFile("$File", basename($File));
    $zip->close();
```

I have added one file already in the zip, which is in variable '$File'. That file exists in the same folder (images). I need to add images in the same zip file. Those images are located inside 'images' folder. I guess I need to scan the images and add them into to same zip. But I'm not sure how to do that.

How can I get specific type(jpeg, png, gif) of files added into an existing zip file or a new one? I have to add images in the root of my zip file, not inside any folder within the zip file. The images are inside one directory('images') and I need to add those into my zip file, which is also saved inside the same directory.

Comment: provide some code because i dont know how to answer you with no specific way you want to do things

Comment: zip_entry_open() 
zip_entry_close()

Comment: I've updated my question, please view it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
        $dir = './property_image';
        $file1 = scandir($dir);
        foreach($file1 as $feel){
            $userfile_extn = substr($feel, strrpos($feel, '.')+1);
            if($userfile_extn === 'jpg' || $userfile_extn === 'png' || $userfile_extn === 'gif' || $userfile_extn === 'jpeg'){
                if(in_array($feel, $prop_image)){
                    //echo $feel;
                    $zip->addFile("./property_image/$feel", basename($feel));
                }

            } // end of if($extension ===

        } // end of foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
if ($zip->open('source.zip') === TRUE) 
{ 
     for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
     {   
        $fp = $zip->getStream($zip->getNameIndex($i));
        if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $contents = fread($fp, 8192);
            // explode for extension and do what ever you want
        }
        fclose($fp);
     }
} 
else 
{ 
     echo 'Error reading zip-archive!'; 
}
```

Comment: I need to check if they are images